# C2039 C2228 'get_value_or': is not a member of 'network::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>'

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, uri

I am trying to compile a piece of code but receive the following errors:

```
error C2039: 'get_value_or': is not a member of 'network::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
note: see declaration of 'network::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>'

error C2228: left of '.get_value_or' must have class/struct/union
```

```
#include "StdInc.h"
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

#include <C:\Users\USER\PROJECT\network\uri\uri.hpp>
#include <C:\Users\USER\PROJECT\network\string_view.hpp>


boost::string_ref scheme = serviceUri.scheme().get_value_or("part1");

if (scheme == "part1")
{
    boost::string_ref hostname = serviceUri.host().get_value_or("localhost");
    int port = serviceUri.port<int>().get_value_or(2800);
```

I am using Visual Basic 2015 Update 3 with Boost 1.57.0

Comment: According to [this reference](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/uri/blob/master/include/network/string_view.hpp) (the best I could find) `network::string_view` has no method called `get_value_or` so I guess the question is why you think it should have. I think some history on how you came by this code, and what modifications you have made to it is needed.

Comment: @john I came to the same conclusion after searching the internet however I do not know what alterations are to be made to make this work. This code is a game server client code I had archived 4 years ago, and at the moment I would like to try and get it sorted. I am a complete noob by all means necessary so I'm very sorry for making more experienced people scratch their heads. This code at the time was claimed to be build ready. I have made 0 modifications to the code apart from changing the last 2 #include to force VS to find the files.

Comment: What library do the `<network\uri\uri.hpp>` and `<network\string_view.hpp>` header files belong to? Or did you write them yourself (is that you use full paths to #include` them)? They are certainly not part of Boost. Look at the methods actually declared in the `network::basic_string_view` class to see what is actually available.

Comment: @9445a4dcb9 I think you've probably just pulled in the wrong library. I've looked around a bit and I can see no evidence that the library I referenced would ever have been able to compile the code you have.

Comment: @9445a4dcb9 It's clear enough what the intent is though. If the specified URL has no scheme use "part1" instead, if it has no host use "localhost", if it has no port use 2800. Maybe you can adapt the code to the library you do have.

Answer (score 0):

You were using [cppnetlib/uri](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/uri).

However, 4 years ago they had (another) [breaking interface change](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/uri/commit/a0ab72605928ca34a04006a442e58a057e00f369):

> Replaced the accessors that return optional string_view objects with two separate functions.

What's worse, they still return a hand-rolled `string_view` instead of the standard one.

Also, their version of `network::optional<>` never had a `get_value_or`. In fact `get_value_or` is Boost-only, [where it is deprecated](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/detailed_semantics.html) in favor of the (standard) `value_or`.

### Conclusion

Use the `has_scheme()` accessor to see whether a scheme is present. You could make an optional out of that:

```
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <network/uri/uri.hpp>
#include <network/string_view.hpp>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    network::uri serviceUri("http://cpp-netlib.org/");

    network::optional<network::string_view> scheme, hostname, port;

    if (serviceUri.has_scheme())
        scheme = serviceUri.scheme();
    if (serviceUri.has_host())
        hostname = serviceUri.host();
    if (serviceUri.has_port())
        port = serviceUri.port();

    scheme   = scheme.value_or("part1");
    hostname = hostname.value_or("localhost");
    port     = scheme.value_or("2800");
}
```

Alternatively, you could steer clear of `network::optional` and `network::string_view` alltogether, and simply write:

```
#include <network/uri/uri.hpp>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    network::uri serviceUri("http://cpp-netlib.org/");

    std::string const scheme = serviceUri.has_scheme()
        ?  serviceUri.scheme().to_string()
        : "part1";

    std::string const host = serviceUri.has_host()
        ?  serviceUri.host().to_string()
        : "localhost";

    std::string const port = serviceUri.has_port()
        ?  serviceUri.port().to_string()
        : "2800";
}
```